# Error when compiling vue and tailwind with npm run dev [Laravel 9]

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, tailwind-css

I'm trying to install Vue 3 and TailwindCSS into my laravel project.

Here's what I did, first, **"npm install vue"**.
Then I install Tailwind with   **"npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest"**.

After that, **"npx tailwindcss init"** to generate **tailwind.config.js**

Then I made changes in **webpack.mix.js** to make sure it compile Vue and Tailwind files

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css", [require("tailwindcss")]);
    
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Then I add the following code in **resources/css/app.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Then I run **npm run dev** then there's the error

```
C:\laragon\www\e-petakom(main -> origin)                                                                                   
λ npm run dev                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                           
> dev                                                                                                                      
> npm run development                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                           
> development                                                                                                              
> mix                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                           
✖ Mix                                                                                                                      
  Compiled with some errors in 3.69s                                                                                       
                                                                                                                           
ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css                                                                                           
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):                                          
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):                                        
Error: Can't resolve 'variables' in 'C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\resources\css'                                               
    at finishWithoutResolve (C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:309:18)                
    at C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:386:15                                       
    at C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:435:5                                        
    at eval (eval at create (C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:435:5                                        
    at eval (eval at create (C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43                           
    at C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:435:5                                        
    at eval (eval at create (C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:435:5                                        
    at processResult (C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:758:19)                            
    at C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:860:5                                             
    at C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:400:11                                      
    at C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:252:18                                      
    at context.callback (C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)                   
    at Object.loader (C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:155:5)                                
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)                                                  
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)                                                               
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:442:9)                                                               
                                                                                                                           
1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)                       
webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

Any idea why is this happening?

I already tried deleting node modules folder from my project.
Execute following commands to make sure all the package is updated
**npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install**

Comment: Something is wrong in your variables file it seems... Can you show it here? `C:\laragon\www\e-petakom\resources\css`

Comment: @SinisaM yeah sure, for some reason StackOverflow wont allow me to post the comment because it is not ignoring the @ symbol but here's the screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/gL6nzVu

Comment: Ye i think you did not import variables properly... you need to got something like: `./variables` or `src/css/variables`. So i think you path is not good.